# Adding Quantities that have same names from 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table that has a part number that contains 15 characters and within this string there are 4 different features contained in the one number. I am taking a query of the table and then stripping out the different strings of numbers to go use then in other tables. The problem I have is when there are multiple sub strings with the same value. I then run it through my bill of material table to get the quantity required to make the overall part. But it is returning duplicates when I would like to get it to return a sum of all duplicates.

This is what I'm doing:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE `active` = '1'");
    while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $bucket_back_num = substr($r['part_num'],0,7);
        $bucket_bottom_num = substr($r['part_num'],0,7);
        $hooks_part_num = substr($r['part_num'],7,11-7);
        $grapple_part_num = substr($r['part_num'],11,15-11);
        $bucket_back_num .= $grapple_part_num;

        $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT *,sum(qty) as qty from bucket_part_bom WHERE `parent_part_num` = '$bucket_back_num' GROUP BY parent_part_num");
        while ($r2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
            echo '
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 15%;">'.$r2['part_num'].'</td>
                    <td style="width: 25%; text-align: left;">'.$r2['desc'].'</td>
                    <td style="width: 15%;">'.$r2['qty'].'</td>
                    <td style="width: 15%;">Unpainted</td>
                    <td style="width: 10%;">Diff</td>
                    <td style="width: 10%;">Build</td>
                    <td style="width: 10%;">N/A</td>
                </tr>
            ';
        }
    }
```

What Is Being returned:

```
LM102BRBK   Bucket Back 102" Light Material Bare    1
LM1023XBK   Bucekt Back 102" Light Material, GF3X   1
LM1023XBK   Bucekt Back 102" Light Material, GF3X   1
```

Comment: What do you want returned instead?

Comment: Each time you print a row, add the part number to an array. Then before printing a row, check whether the part number is already in the array, and skip it if it is.

Comment: A couple of warnings here: 1) You should be using prepared statements even here.  (You can't use it for `$table`, unfortunately, but it needs to be checked against a whitelist).  2) Every column not in the `GROUP BY`/an aggregate function gets a non-deterministic (for you) value.  For example - in the rows it is returning, which is the correct description, `"Bucket Back 102" Light Material Bare"`, or `Bucekt Back 102" Light Material, GF3X"`?  If you only have 1 item, which one do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine the two queries into a single query with a `JOIN`

```
SELECT t.*, b.*, SUM(b.qty) AS qty
FROM $table AS t
JOIN bucket_part_bom AS b ON b.parent_part_num = SUBSTR(t.part_num, 1, 7)
GROUP BY b.parent_part_num
```